# Why won't my game package to my iphone in unreal engine 5

Tags: unreal-5

I made a game and I want to export it to iOS and it kept saying "The Binaries for this Target Platform are not currently installed" and I did what it told me to do which is to install it, but is still says that even when I did that.

Comment: Can you walk us through the exact steps you took to install the iOS binaries?

Comment: What I did was I went to the options and then I clicked on iOS and applied.